# 6-digit passcode that contain exactly one multiple of 3 if digits can be repeated.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Each element being any digits from 0 to 9. How many possible passcodes are there?

Tried doing $3 * 6 * 9 * 3 * 6 * 9$ but that's not exactly ONE multiple of 3.

Comment: So exactly one digit must be $0,3,6$ or $9$ and the remaining five must be $1,2,4,5,7,8$?

Answer (score 1):

One of the digits must be $0,3,6$ or $9$.  The remaining $5$ must be $1,2,4,5,7,8$

You have $6$ choose for which digit is the multiple of three.  And you have $4$ choices for which multiple of three it is.  For the remaining five digits, you have $6$ choices which each one is.

So you have $6*4*6*6*6*6*6 = 4*6^5$ possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* I understand your question.

The multiples of $3$ are of course $3,6,9$.  You can place exactly one of these in one of six slots.  There are five remaining slots, with seven permissible digits for each:  $0,1,2,4,5,7,8$.

So:  three candidate "3 multiples" times 6 possible slots for that "multiple" times $7^5$ remaining "non-multiples."

If you count $0$ as a "3 multiple," then the answer changes in a straightforward manner:

$(4 \times 6) \times 6^5$.

Comment: $0$ is a multiple of $3$.